# To allow for possible reopening, you may delete in 2 days

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-questions

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368644/patenting-an-idea-closed) which is apparently not software related. So, I wanted to delete it. Then I get "To allow for possible reopening, you may delete in 2 days." Now, I am geting downvotes since it's not software related. How can I delete it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention and ask to have it deleted. That'll circumvent the 2 day wait and you'll regain any lost rep on the next rep recalc. Or you can explicitly request a rep recalc with the same flag for moderator attention approach (but ask nicely).

Comment: It worked! YEY!! :) THANKS.

Answer (score -1):

Edit to make it community wiki.

Comment: What does Community Wiki have to do with it? If the question does not fall under the guidelines of acceptable material, I don't see how changing it to a CW post is going to make it any more valid.

Comment: *facepalm* *facepalm* *facepalm* *facepalm* *facepalm*

Comment: @TheTXI -- The OP will stop losing rep from it, which seems to be the main complaint.

Comment: Absolutely do *not* make community wiki, as there is [little reason for it's existence anymore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).